# Compare field values of two consecutive rows and filter the results by this comparison

Tags: mysql

I have a table with DATETIME column.

In the normal case, I insert a row every hour with the current time, so I have rows with a time interval of 1 hour, such 2018-01-28 09:00:00, 2018-01-28 10:00:00, etc.

My problem is that sometimes my code does not insert a row for a few hours, so I have a gap of times, and the interval suddenly grows.

What I need is a way to select only the latest continuous rows, with a 1-hour interval.

For example, if I have the times 2018-01-28 10:00:00, 2018-01-28 09:00:00, and then 2018-01-28 05:00:00, the query should fetch only the first two and nothing else.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could use self join to compare values of different rows from the same table. 
Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT (t2.field_to_compare - t1.field_to_compare) AS your_interval
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.field_to_compare < t2.field_to_compare
ORDER BY t1.field_to_compare;
```